# Ionic cordova run android results into build errors

Tags: firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-dynamic-links

I recently installed Firebase Dynamic Links : https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase-dynamic-links

Then tried running my Ionic 4 App : `ionic cordova run android --livereload`

All of a sudden started encountering with below build errors :

> [cordova] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> [cordova]
>   [cordova] * What went wrong:
>
> [cordova] Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   [cordova] > In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[20.0.
>   [cordova]   0]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.
>
> [cordova]
>   [cordova]   Dependency failing: com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0 -> com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@[20.0.0], but fire
>   [cordova]   base-iid version was 20.0.2.
>   [cordova]
>
> [cordova]   The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have transitive dependencies that lead to the art
>   [cordova]   ifact with the issue.
>   [cordova]   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@20.0.0
>   [cordova]   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics@17.2.2
>   [cordova]   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api@17.2.2
>   [cordova]   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-config@19.0.3
>   [cordova]   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager-api@17.0.0
>   [cordova]   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@20.0.2
>   [cordova]   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager@17.0.0
>   [cordova]   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@19.0.1
>
> [cordova]
>   [cordova]   For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with ./gradlew --info :app:assembleDebug to see the dep
>   [cordova]   endency paths to the artifact. This error message came from the google-services Gradle plugin, report issues at https://
>   [cordova]   github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding "googleServices { disableVersionCheck = false }" to your build.gradle file.

My package.json :

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "~8.1.2",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^5.21.5",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/deeplinks": "^5.19.1",
    "@ionic-native/device": "^5.19.1",
    "@ionic-native/fcm": "^5.21.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^5.21.5",
    "@ionic-native/firebase-authentication": "^5.21.2",
    "@ionic-native/firebase-dynamic-links": "^5.21.6",
    "@ionic-native/firebase-x": "^5.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/native-storage": "^5.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^5.21.6",
    "@ionic-native/paypal": "^5.19.1",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^5.19.1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/web-intent": "^5.19.1",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.7.1",
    "angular-notification-icons": "^1.0.0",
    "card.io.cordova.mobilesdk": "^2.1.0",
    "com-darryncampbell-cordova-plugin-intent": "^2.0.0",
    "com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk": "^3.5.0",
    "com.razorpay.cordova": "^1.4.8",
    "cordova-android": "^8.1.0",
    "cordova-browser": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx": "^1.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": "^1.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-firebasex": "^8.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": "^2.3.2",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^5.6.3",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^4.0.0",
    "cordova-support-android-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "cordova-support-google-services": "^1.3.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "firebase": "^7.7.0",
    "ionic-plugin-deeplinks": "^1.0.20",
    "ng-spinners": "^1.1.1",
    "ngx-countdown": "^8.0.3",
    "ngx-spinner": "^8.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.801.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.801.2",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.1.2",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "ionic-plugin-deeplinks": {
        "URL_SCHEME": "mytourngapp",
        "DEEPLINK_SCHEME": "https",
        "DEEPLINK_HOST": "sachin.com",
        "ANDROID_PATH_PREFIX": "/",
        "ANDROID_2_PATH_PREFIX": "/",
        "ANDROID_3_PATH_PREFIX": "/",
        "ANDROID_4_PATH_PREFIX": "/",
        "ANDROID_5_PATH_PREFIX": "/",
        "DEEPLINK_2_SCHEME": " ",
        "DEEPLINK_2_HOST": " ",
        "DEEPLINK_3_SCHEME": " ",
        "DEEPLINK_3_HOST": " ",
        "DEEPLINK_4_SCHEME": " ",
        "DEEPLINK_4_HOST": " ",
        "DEEPLINK_5_SCHEME": " ",
        "DEEPLINK_5_HOST": " "
      },
      "com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk": {},
      "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "24.1.1+"
      },
      "com-darryncampbell-cordova-plugin-intent": {},
      "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": {},
      "com.razorpay.cordova": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks": {
        "APP_DOMAIN": "tourng.com",
        "PAGE_LINK_DOMAIN": "tourng.page.link",
        "FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_VERSION": "17.2.+",
        "FIREBASE_DYNAMIC_LINKS_VERSION": "19.1.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-firebasex": {
        "ANDROID_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_VERSION": "20.0.0",
        "FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_ENABLED": "true",
        "FIREBASE_PERFORMANCE_COLLECTION_ENABLED": "true",
        "FIREBASE_CRASHLYTICS_COLLECTION_ENABLED": "true",
        "ANDROID_ICON_ACCENT": "#FF00FFFF",
        "ANDROID_PLAY_SERVICES_TAGMANAGER_VERSION": "17.0.0",
        "ANDROID_PLAY_SERVICES_AUTH_VERSION": "17.0.0",
        "ANDROID_FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_VERSION": "17.2.1",
        "ANDROID_FIREBASE_CONFIG_VERSION": "19.0.3",
        "ANDROID_FIREBASE_PERF_VERSION": "19.0.1",
        "ANDROID_FIREBASE_AUTH_VERSION": "19.1.0",
        "ANDROID_CRASHLYTICS_VERSION": "2.10.1",
        "ANDROID_CRASHLYTICS_NDK_VERSION": "2.1.1"
      }
    },
    "platforms": [
      "browser",
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

Help me build my App again :(

**PS** : I don't want to disable VersionCheck of googleServices as it might have side effects later.